# how do I find the id of the minimum value of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know that you can have the minimum value of an array by typing

```
var min = Math.min.apply(null, array)
```

but this will return the smallest value of an array and not the id of this one
for exemple if I have these values:

```
array[1] = 24;
array[2] = 45;
```

I want it to return 1 (the ID holding the minimum value) but idk how to do, could someone help me with this issue please?

Comment: Does maintaining the original order of the elements in the array matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var index = array.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, array));
```

Comment: This only works if there is an item in the 0th position of the array. For the array given I get -1 because the min value is NaN.

Comment: @jcollum you can get around uninitialised properties of an _Array_ using `.filter(function () {return true;})`

Comment: @jcollum : think before answering, please. If 'there's no item in the Oth position', it means the array is empty, so -1 is a good answer : there is no minimum, hence no minimum index.

Comment: @VincentPiel consider `a = []; a[3] = 1;`, indicies _0, 1, 2_ are not initialised, but the _Array_ is non-empty.

Comment: I assume the OP is not using a sparse array and that the example is figurative. But you have a valid point...

Comment: But this is not the best solution. It must iterate the array two times to find the value. The answer from @user2736012 is better.

Comment: @VincentPiel "think before answering, please" -- you should take your own advice. This code fails for an array like `[undefined, 24, 45]` -- which is exactly what OP provided. You're being rude.

Comment: @PedroL. It's true that it's possible to do this in one pass. I would disagree that his solution is better though. One could even argue that it's a form of premature optimization. I prefer readable, maintainable code first and foremost.

Comment: @PaulS. my point is that the code provided fails for the array provided -- he probably meant to put something in the 0 position but it is what it is

Comment: @finishingmove I get an error saying array.indexOf.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array#reduce()` to get the smallest number, while avoiding holes in the Array if needed.

```
array.reduce(function(obj, n, i) {
    if (n < obj.min)
        obj.i = i;
    return obj;
}, {min:Infinity,i:-1}).i;
```

---

Or if performance and compatibility is a concern, you could just loop.

```
var res = -1;
var min = Infinity;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if ((i in array) && array[i] < min) {
         min = array[i];
         res = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns the lowest value, not the index of the lowest value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var id = array.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got the value, you can use `indexOf` to get the index, like this:

```
var index = array.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, array));
```

You should be aware that `indexOf` was only recently included in JavaScript (ES5/JS 1.6 to be precise) so you may want to find some wrapper for it if the function does not exist.

See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for more information (which contains an example implementation of a backwards compatible function).

Answer (score 0):

Just like the algorithm for finding the min value, but you have to track the minimum index as well

```
function minIndex(arr) {
    if (!arr || arr.length === 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    var min = arr[0];
    var minIndex = 0;
    for (var len = arr.length; len > 0; len--) {
        if (arr[len] < min) {
            min = arr[len];
            minIndex = len;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
```

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SeJVT/)